# Trying to make a soup.select for multiple cases

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

today I'm scratching my head on this problem.

Basically I'm using this code:

```
    for link in soup.select(".lif__pricing"):
        list_prices.append(link.get_text(strip=True))
```

to find all the `.lif__princing` tags and get the price from them.

Here come my problem: I use the list to put it next to a column on titles related to the prices, but sometimes the prices are not listed and instead they use a tag `.lif__pricing--wrapped` and the list gets basically 1 row behind the titles list.

So to make you better understand what I can't for the life of me achieve, here is the logic code one would do:

```
    for link in soup.select(".lif__pricing" and ".lif__pricing--wrapped"):
        list_prices.append(link.get_text(strip=True))
```

How can I make this code, but that does't give me only the ones for `.lif__pricing--wrapped`...

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get tags with class `"lif__pricing"` **and** `"lif__pricing--wrapped"` use:

```
for link in soup.select(".lif__pricing, .lif__pricing--wrapped"):
    list_prices.append(link.get_text(strip=True))
```

For mode info, you can use [CSS selector guide](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: I'm dumb, thanks for this and thanks for the link to the guide! Also, it's always you Andrej, you are my saviour!